# How to write a Python compound key, value dictionary to a database?

Tags: python, performance, sqlite, dictionary, insert

I have a compound-key dictionary in Python like this:

```
key          value
("a","b")    (1,2,3)
("c","d")    (4,5,6)
("e","f")    (7,8,9)
```

Both the key and value are tuples. I would like to save it in the most efficient way possible to a sqlite database table like this:

```
row    col1   col2   col3   col4   col5
1      "a"    "b"    1      2      3
2      "c"    "d"    4      5      6
3      "e"    "f"    7      8      9
```

To do this I was trying to join the keys and values line-by-line, then pass this structure to  executemany() with INSERT. This works, but is extremely slow:

```
writedata = []

for i in range(0, len(mydict.keys())):
    writedata.append(mydict.keys()[i] + mydict.values()[i])

sql = "INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"
mydbcursor.executemany(sql, writedata)
```

I have a very large dataset, so ideally I don't even want to create a secondary structure like writedata above.

I've tried following many solutions here on SO (list comprehension, list +, list extend, generators, ...) but I haven't found the right recipe to deal with this case.

Any help or links would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Cursor.executemany()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany) works fine with iterators as well:

> The sqlite3 module also allows using an iterator yielding parameters
>   instead of a sequence.

So, you can pass an generator to it instead of creating an intermediate list first:

```
mydbcursor.executemany(sql, (k + v for k, v in mydict.iteritems()))
```

In Python3 `.iteritems()` won't work, there you can use `.items()` which returns a view of the items instead if creating a list in memory.

We can get a little more speed up if we completely remove `for` loop from our code by using `itertools.starmap` with `operator.add`:

```
mydbcursor.executemany(sql, starmap(add, dct.iteritems())
```

Timing comparisons suggest consuming the above iterator takes less time:

```
In [34]: from operator import add                                                                                                                

In [35]: from itertools import starmap                                                                                                    

In [36]: dct = {(i, 'a', 'b'): (1, 2, 3) for i in xrange(10**6)}

In [37]: %timeit for _ in (k+v for k, v in dct.iteritems()): pass                                                                                
1 loops, best of 3: 290 ms per loop                                                                                                              

In [38]: %timeit for _ in starmap(add, dct.iteritems()): pass                                                                                    
1 loops, best of 3: 256 ms per loop   

In [39]: %timeit list(starmap(add, dct.iteritems()))                                                                                             
1 loops, best of 3: 335 ms per loop                                                                                                              

In [40]: %timeit list(k+v for k, v in dct.iteritems())                                                                                           
1 loops, best of 3: 415 ms per loop
```

Comment: This will be fast, and won't consume extra memory by building a second data structure as in the OP's solution. Look into boosting the speed of sqlite, maybe by temporarily turning off indexes?

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic answer! Saw a 30x speed improvement in the overall function when I moved from the version in the post to this solution. Really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be:

```
writedata = [key + value for key, value in mydict.items()]
```

If it isn't fast after that then it may simply be the large amount of data. The above code avoids indexing and lots of function calls so it should be marginally faster than what you've written.

Whatever approach you take it ultimately has to be turned into a SQL query. So while you can avoid intermediate data structures you'll still need to build the query.

Comment: Thanks Simeon for the response. This answer as well resulted in a huge performance increase over the function I had included in the original post.